# Oozie shell action failed to exec java in Linux

Tags: java, oozie, oozie-workflow

We have submit below Oozie workflow job. It executed in windows cluster but in Linux it is failed.

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.3' name='shell-wf'>
    <start to='shell1' />
    <action name='shell1'>
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>Java</exec>
            <argument>A</argument>
            <argument>B</argument>
            <file>${EXEC}#${EXEC}</file> <!--Copy the executable to compute node's current working directory -->
        </shell>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

But when i execute the above workflow file, it throw's exception **can not run java program. No such file or directory**.

Comment: Since you don't provide *any* information about the actual parameters, especially `EXEC`, I can't imagine how you can expect any kind of help.

Comment: By the way, what do think your `<file>${EXEC}#${EXEC}</file>` is supposed to do? Especially the `#` instruction?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a shell action for a shell script, and any of the commands have failed in the shell script, you have to add the line `#!/bin/bash -e` in your shell script to capture the failure code for the transition. Then it will be captured in the output, and only your workflow will be killed.  Otherwise it will exit as successful even though the shell action might have had a failure.